# Edit Enterprise Calendar in Project Server 2010

Tags: microsoft-project

Has anyone been able to successfully edit the Standard calendar in 2010?

I'm trying to change the working times as none of our admin accounts seem able to do it.  We're running Project Server 2010 RTM on SharePoint 2010 RTM with Project Pro 2010.

When I click the Edit Calendar button in PWA it triggers Project client to open up but it just opens up an empty project and I've not access to edit the Standard calendar using any of the published steps.

It would be great to hear if someone has managed to do this so I can work out if it's a general glitch in this build or is it just a problem with out setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed - our farm was originally setup with NTLM authentication and I've just been through the process to setup SPNs etc to switch across to Kerberos.  On a whim I thought I'd try Project Server again and was able to update the calendar without any issues hence it must have been an auth problem that wasn't being handled well within the app.